# Inlcude binarize methods in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, image-processing, user-interface

I would require the binarize methods in the Manipulate interface.
Thanks

```
    Manipulate[
    Binarize[insertImage, binOnly], {binOnly, 0, 
    1}, {Method -> 
    method}, {{method, {"Cluster"}, {"Entropy", "Mean", 
    "MinimumError"}}}]
```

```
Manipulate[Binarize[Method[insertImage, bin1],
] {Method, {"Cluster", "Entropy", "Mean", "MinimumError"}}, {bin1, 
0, 1}]
```

Comment: ... and? What is the problem? Please be more specific about your question.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Row[{"Binarize[insertImage,", binOnly, ",Method\[Rule]", 
      method, "]"}]},
   {Binarize[insertImage, binOnly, Method -> method]}
   }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}],
 {{binOnly, .6, "binOnly"}, 0, 1, .1},
 {{method, "Cluster", "method"}, {"Entropy", "Mean", "MinimumError"}},
 TrackedSymbols :> {method, binOnly}
 ]
```

Any other image can be used. For example `insertImage = Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"]`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,
but the output image does not change for the methods

````
With[{im =image},
Manipulate[Binarize[im, bim,

   Method -> method1], {bim, 0, 1},
  {{method1, "Cluster"}, {"Cluster", "Entropy", "Mean", 
    "MinimumError"}}]]
```
````

Comment: does the image change for the method if you do not use `With`? i.e. if you just use as shown in the above answer, does it work then?