# Construct UI for image

Tags: manipulate, image-processing, image, user-interface

I am trying to build the User interface, whereby when binarize is clicked, it gives its slider and its respective MeanIntensity and StandardDeviation.
The same for EdgeDetect and MorpologicalBinarize.
I attached the expected output
Kindly please help in it.Thank you for your consideration

[image: Expected output]

```
With[{img1 =image},
Manipulate[
  Show[
   segmentation[
    Binarize[img1, a],
    EdgeDetect[img1, b],
    MorphologicalBinarize[img1, c],
    {{a1, {a, 0, 1}}, {{b1, {b, 1, 2}}, {{c1, {c, 0, 1}}}}}]],

  measurement[
   ImageMeasurements[a1, "MeanIntensity"],
   ImageMeasurements[a1, "StandardDeviation"],
   ImageMeasurements[b1, "MeanIntensity"],
   ImageMeasurements[b1, "StandardDeviation"],
   ImageMeasurements[c1, "MeanIntensity"],
   ImageMeasurements[c1, "StandardDeviation"]],

  {segmentation, {"Binarize"   , "Edge Detect"    , 
    "Morphological Binarize"}},
  {{measurement, "Mean"}, {"Mean", "Standard Deviation"}}]]
```

Comment: You asked same question here [inlcude-binarize-methods-in-manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220482/inlcude-binarize-methods-in-manipulate) and when asked there to clarify when you have to use `With` you did not reply. So how is this question different from your last question?  `Kindly please help in it.` What exactly is the issue here? You just said to help. But did not describe what is the problem.

Comment: Hi, because, I found that according to the documentation: "If an explicit threshold value is given, Binarize ignores the Method option." So, I will use this method, but the code I am writing is giving me error.